# why a[6] showing 344 value

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
  int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    printf("%d",a[6]);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Que : Why a[6] is showing 344 value, why not zero. Where this value came from ?

Comment: Indexing an array out of bounds leads to undefined behavior, which means anything could happen. Just don't do it.

Comment: [sigh] 'I did a bad thing.  I knew I did a bad thing.  Bad things happened as a result.  Why?'

Answer (score 3):

C does not check if you are going out of bound for an `array`. If you do so, it is **undefined behavior**, then you will get garbage value, in worst case, you can get a **seg fault** also.

Answer (score 0):

Because a[6] is somewhere in memory which you don't know what holds.
In your case its 344.

Your compiler won't tell you that you are out of bound.

Comment: If i print only a[6] instead of using loop like printf("%d",a[6]); Here it will show zero value .Why ? Why there is not Garbage

Comment: @Aniket: `a[6]` is nowhere (as is `a[5]` already, btw). Accessing is UB, thus no further research required. Anything can happen, prepare for nasal demons, your computer walks away, etc.